# My Dash does not show recent applications. What can I do to fix that?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, zeitgeist

For some unknown reason, my Unity dash doesn't show recent applications. I am guessing it could be related to the fact that I have a newer version of zeitgeist than the standard repo provides (I use a ppa).

That is the only unusual detail I can think of. What can I do to get back recent applications in the dash?

Comment: Do you have zeitgeist 0.8.0.0 from this [Zeitgeist PPA](https://launchpad.net/~zeitgeist/+archive/ppa)?

Comment: @Manish as far as I remember.

Comment: @Manish could that be the reason?

Comment: taylor Still need to investigate. It would be great if someone from Unity team could look into this. I will try to find out someone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a similar problem [reported here](https://answers.launchpad.net/zeitgeist/+question/162578)

The solution was to reinstall `unity-lens-applications` and `unity-lens-files` packages and the Dash magically works.

Both these packages were formely named `unity-place-applications` and `unity-place-files`

We are looking into it. Probably some packaging issue.

Comment: I had marked this as solved, but after testing I still have the problem :'(. I restarted unity it still won't show any recent applications. Recent files work just fine.

Comment: It doesn't show just "Recent Applications" or no Applications at all?

Comment: Only recent applications don't show.

Comment: This means this is an issue with `Recent Applications` with Unity Dash. Since recently used applications does indeed use Zeitgeist, so I guess this needs to be investigated. If this issue is too much troubling, then you can try to downgrade the zeitgeist version by opening in Synaptic and do a `"Force version"` to the version which comes with Ubuntu. By the time I can find a solution

Comment: I'll just leave it as is. I have Synapse, so I am not too highly bothered, and I can use my system as a test bed for providing info toward fixing it :).

Comment: That will be cool. Thanks for the help. I use both `Dash` and `Synapse`. I use both `Unity Launcher` and `Docky`

Comment: Lol same here :D!

Comment: I'm having the same problem, Recent Files is fine but I don't have Recent Apps.

Comment: @ManishSinha How do I reinstall it? When I do "apt-get install --reinstall unity-place-applications" it says it's unable to locate package. What do I do?

Comment: @jaorizabal I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In my case none of the solutions above worked.

The solution I found to work:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/zeitgeist
```

Then close your session and login again, and dash worked again.

Answer (score 0):

for recent apps to show in dash in ubuntu 16.04
turning on record file and application usage (in security & privacy)
worked for me

[snap shot - record file and application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2onHx.jpg)