# Ubuntu 12.04 Dash Home looses apps frequently

Tags: unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My Dash does not show recent applications. What can I do to fix that?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48100/my-dash-does-not-show-recent-applications-what-can-i-do-to-fix-that)

I have tried the various suggested fixes, some of which did nothing, others seemed to fix the problem for a day or two but it soon returned.

Dash Home simply shows recent files and downloads no Apps at all.

Can anyone help please.

Comment: It would be useful to those who might help you if you listed the things you've already tried.

Comment: originally:

mv ~/.local/share/zeitgeist  ~/.local/share/zeitgeist.bak which after a reload worked, but a couple of days later apps again disappeared. Also tried unity --reset but this ran for quite a time then hung my Laptop. Repeated
mv ~/.local/share/zeitgeist  ~/.local/share/zeitgeist.bak which after a reload worked, but again a couple of days later apps again disappeared. Dash just displayed Files and Downloads.

Comment: Now when I try the same instruction I get the following error:  john@john-Aspire-3610:~$ mv ~/.local/share/zeitgeist  ~/.local/share/zeitgeist.bak 
mv: cannot move `/home/john/.local/share/zeitgeist' to `/home/john/.local/share/zeitgeist.bak/zeitgeist': Directory not empty 
john@john-Aspire-3610:~$

Comment: This morning when I logged on everything was back to normal, but this evening no Apps are showing at all on Dash Home. I have restarted my laptop but to no avail.

Comment: I have worked out that something is putting back zeitgeist so when it is moved to a .bak file then everything is ok, but what ever is putting it back into my .local/share/ causes my Dash Home to view everything except my Apps.

Comment: Have you tried the other solutions offered [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/125843/dash-search-gives-no-result)?  Did you install a newer Zeitgeist via PPA or are you using the Ubuntu shipped version?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I loaded Ubuntu 12.04 LTS direct from a DVD afresh, and then loaded loads of Apps. My Dash Home comes and goes at will!! Sometimes it's there intact displaying Apps, Files, Downloads etc.. and then suddenly only displays the files and Downloads etc.. but no Apps. I did try the recommendation but got the following: john@john-Aspire-3610:~$ ~/.local/share/zeitgeist/activity.sqlite
bash: /home/john/.local/share/zeitgeist/activity.sqlite: Permission denied
john@john-Aspire-3610:~$ 
and being a novice no sure how to overcome this, and I am the only user.

Comment: Also, I see that this question has been closed as an exact duplicate, but how do I see the original item? Looking at FAQ's I have had to page down numerous pages and still cannot find the original item. Is there an easy way to find the original item and its suggested fixes directly?

Comment: @Insperatus can you please advise where I can find the item that describes precisely what I need to do to resolve this issue. I have tried everything that I have found in other notes and still my Dash Home looses Apps frequently and suddenly they return, but it is very unusable. I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS from DVD and did not upgrade from an earlier version.

Comment: Directly below the title of your question it suggests the possible duplicate - **you can click on that, it is hypertext**.  The `permission denied` error you were receiving is because you need to preface the command with "sudo" - no quotes.  Try `sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/zeitgeist` and then log out and back in to test it.

Comment: @insperatus So far so good, so hoping it will now remain stable. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome, I'll keep my fingers crossed :)

Comment: @insperatus, no it's lost the Apps again and I have not done anything other than access the internet! Never mind I can at least use the File Manager and it's Application list to find what I need. Regards John. :)